# Monitoring runtime use of concrete collections

Tags: scala, collections, jvm, runtime, monitoring

**Background:**
Our Scala software consists of various components, *developed by different teams*, that pass Scala collections back and forth. The APIs usually use abstract collections such as `Seq[T]` and `Set[T]`, and developers are currently essentially free to choose any implementation they like: e.g. when creating new instances, some go with `List()` or `Vector()`, others with `Seq.empty`.

**Problem:**
[Different implementations have different performance characteristics](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html), e.g. `List` might have been a good choice locally (for one component) because the collection is only sequentially iterated over or modified at the head, but it could have been a poor choice globally, because another component performs loads of random accesses.

**Question:**
Are their any tools — ideally Scala-specific, but JVM-general might also be OK — that can monitor *runtime use* of collections and record the information necessary to detect and report undesirable access/usage patterns of collections?

My feeling is that runtime monitoring would be more fruitful than static analyses (including simple linting) because (i) statically detecting usage patterns *in hot code* is virtually impossible, and (ii) would most likely miss collections that are internally created, e.g. when performing complex filter/map/fold/etc. operations on immutable collections.

**Edits/Clarifications:**

- Changing the interfaces to enforce specific types such as `List` isn't an option; it would also not prevent purely internal use of "wrong" collections/usage patterns.
- The goal is identifying a globally optimal (over many runs of the software) collection type rather than locally optimising for each applied algorithm

Comment: If you have an algorithm that is affected by collection type it should either convert the incoming data to an appropriate type, or use a more specific collection type on the interface. Use a typeclass for more fine-grained choice of acceptable collection types.

Comment: @Tim Data conversion doesn't come for free. Monitoring might give a chance for finding a globally optimal collection type (over many runs of the software) rather than locally optimising for each algorithm.

Comment: There is no such thing as "globaly optimal collection type". Different algorithms have different characteristics. Data conversion in linear time is "free" for most practical purposes.

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff For any significant algorithm the cost of data conversion will be negligible, and may well improve performance. I strongly suggest that you locally optimise each algorithm by using the best structure for that algorithm, with data conversion if necessary. You will get far more benefit from this than from trying to find one single data structure that gives good performance for every algorithm. For example, if a data copy turns an algorithm from `O(n^2)` to `O(n log n)` the performance benefit will dwarf any conversion cost.

Comment: @Tim The system basically constitutes a heuristics-driven, iterative decision engine where, depending on the heuristics, several different algorithms may be invoked in each iteration, which notably complicates a meaningful complexity analysis. Runtime monitoring would give us more insight into typical executions (in our problem domain); a subsequent analysis might then indeed suggest the kind of local optimisations you mentioned — or, on the contrary, suggest that repeated data structure conversions outweigh the locally achieved benefits. Gaining these insights is what I'm interested in first.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need linting for this, let alone runtime monitoring. This is exactly what having a strictly-typed language does for you out of the box.  If you want to ensure a particular collection type is passed to the API, just declare that that API accepts *that* collection type (e.g., `def foo(x: Stream[Bar])`, not `def foo(x: Seq[Bar])`, etc.).

Alternatively, when practical, just convert to the desired type as part of implementation: `def foo(x: List[Bar]) = { val y = x.toArray ; lotsOfRandomAccess(y); }`

Collections that are "internally created" are typically the same type as the parent object: `List(1,2,3).map(_ + 1)` returns a `List` etc.
Again, if you want to ensure you are using a particular type, just say so:

```
 val mapped: List[Int] = List(1,2,3).map(_ + 1)
```

You can actually, *change* the type this way if there is a need for that:

```
 val mappedStream: Stream[Int] = List(1,2,3).map(_ + 1)(breakOut)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Interfaces are unlikely to change any time soon, though, so enforcing `List` etc. that way isn't an option. It would also not prevent purely internal use of "wrong" usage. Moreover, "are typically the same type", although you're right, isn't good enough (at least for the sake of this question). Theoretically, it could happen that temporary collections are created when chaining operations (e.g. `xs.map(...).zip(...).fold(...)...`), which might not be of the type of the final collection (more type annotations might help, though). I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: "Interfaces are unlikely to change" - of course they won't change by themselves. _You_ should change them :). It is starting to sound like an XY-problem to me.

Comment: Also, not sure what you mean by purely internal wrong usage". Someone writes an algorithm using an `Array` when `List` would be a better choice? You won't catch that with runtime monitoring either - how will your monitor know what is the right type for that specific case? This is what code reviews are for.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, this is a problem that needs to be solved at a local level rather than via global optimisation.

Each algorithm in the system will work best with a particular data type, so using a single global structure will never be optimal. Instead, each algorithm should ensure that the incoming data is in a format that can be processed efficiently. If it is not in the right format, the data should be converted to a better format as the first part of the process. Since the algorithm works better on the right format, this conversion is always a performance improvement.

The output data format is more of a problem if the system does not know which algorithm will be used next. The solution is to use the most efficient output format for the algorithm in question, and rely on other algorithms to re-format the data if required.

---

If you do want to monitor the whole system, it would be better to track the algorithms rather than the collections. If you monitor which algorithms are called and in which order you can create multiple traces through the code. You can then play back those traces with different algorithms and data structures to see which is the most efficient configuration.